# Replace elements in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML like below showing RoadPart and Vehicles elements:

```
<RoadPart>
    <Vehicles>
        <ConfigurationSummaryListPosition>
          <ConfigurationSummary>Test name</ConfigurationSummary>
        </ConfigurationSummaryListPosition>
    </Vehicles>
    <Vehicles>
        <ConfigurationSummaryListPosition>
          <ConfigurationSummary>Test name</ConfigurationSummary>
        </ConfigurationSummaryListPosition>
    </Vehicles>
    <Vehicles>
        <ConfigurationSummaryListPosition>
          <ConfigurationSummary>Test name</ConfigurationSummary>
        </ConfigurationSummaryListPosition>
    </Vehicles>
</RoadPart>
```

I have a variable

```
var test = @"<DataType>
                <ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
                  <ConfigurationSummaryType> name </ConfigurationSummaryType>
                </ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
            </DataType>
            <DataType>
                <ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
                  <ConfigurationSummaryType> Test</ConfigurationSummaryType>
                </ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
            </DataType>";
```

Want to replace vehicle elements with variable output should be as follows :

```
<RoadPart>
    <DataType>
        <ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
          <ConfigurationSummaryType> name </ConfigurationSummaryType>
        </ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
    </DataType>
    <DataType>
        <ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
          <ConfigurationSummaryType> Test</ConfigurationSummaryType>
        </ConfigurationSummaryListPositionType>
    </DataType>
</RoadPart>
```

Help me on this

Comment: `"<RoadPart>" + var + "</RoadPart>"` probably isn't the answer you're looking for. How are the `Vehicles` and `DataType` elements related? Or should you remove all `Vehicles` and add all `DataType` elements?

Comment: Yes i want to remove all vehicles and add variable. help me on this

Comment: We need some clarification. Is the "Test name" relevant in any way, is the number of <Vehicles> tags important, ...

Comment: I have changed now var with name.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't read the xml with linq, reiterate through each node and change that node value.

```
var nodes = (from node in document.Descendant("RoadPart") select node);
```

where document is the loaded xml file

```
var document = XDocument.Load("your xml file path");
```

then eiterate foreach node in your document like this

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the result as `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`:

```
test = string.Concat("<root>", test, "</root>"); // set dummy root
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(test);

XElement replaced = new XElement("RoadPart", xdoc.Descendants("DataType").Select(e => e));
```

If you want to save the result as a file,

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("{filePath}", FileMode.Create))
{
    replaced.Save(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```